# Having trouble understanding how fs.stat() works

Tags: node.js, stat

I'm trying to write a function that tells me is a certain path is a directory.

```
var fs = require('fs');
console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
fs.statSync(pathname, function(err, stats) {
    console.log(stats.isDirectory());
});
console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
```

However, it never prints the answer.

If pathname exists - it doesn't call the function.
If it doesn't exists, it generates an exception: `ENOENT not a file or directory`.
I don't want to know it pathname exists, but I want to know if it's a directory.

Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: It's old yeah, but maybe a quick look into the documentation would've helped..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are using the synchronous version, which doesn't use a callback.  It simply returns the result instead.  So either use the async form `fs.stat(path, callback)` or use the sync form like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
var stats = fs.statSync(pathname);
console.log(stats.isDirectory());
console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
```

Answer (score 16):

How fs.stat() works ?

If you want to use a callback/async fs function, don't use the synchronous version, use fs.stat() :

```
var fs = require('fs');
console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
fs.stat(pathname, function(err, stats) {
    console.log(stats.isDirectory());
});
console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
```

There is more information about [fs.stat()](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html#fs.stat). You can get a lot of information about the main object :

```
fs.stat(path, function(err, stats) {
      console.log(stats)
}
```

Output :

```
{ dev: 2049,
  ino: 305352,
  mode: 16877,
  nlink: 12,
  uid: 1000,
  gid: 1000,
  rdev: 0,
  size: 4096,
  blksize: 4096,
  blocks: 8,
  atime: '2009-06-29T11:11:55Z',
  mtime: '2009-06-29T11:11:40Z',
  ctime: '2009-06-29T11:11:40Z' }
```

Lots of elements is often useless for us, yes. But here is the signification of all of these variables, [according to this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2266929&seqNum=2) :

- **dev:** ID of the device containing the file
- **mode:** file protection
- **nlink:** number of hard links to the file
- **uid:** user ID of the file’s owner.
- **gid:** group ID of the file’s owner.
- **rdev:** device ID if the file is a special file.
- **blksize:** block size for file system I/O.
- **ino:** File inode number. An inode is a file system data structure that stores information about a file.
- **size:** file total size in bytes.
- **blocks:** number of blocks allocated for the file.
- **atime:** date object representing the file’s last access time.
- **mtime:** date object representing the file’s last modification time.
- **ctime:** date object representing the last time the file’s inode was changed.

You can also, like [nodeJS documentation says](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html#fs.Stats), get more information like :

```
stats.isFile()
stats.isDirectory()
stats.isBlockDevice()
stats.isSymbolicLink() (only valid with fs.lstat())
stats.isCharacterDevice()
stats.isFIFO()
stats.isSocket()
```

About stats.isSymbolicLink(), there is another function than fs.stat, called fs.lstat(), and here is the difference between them :

- `stat` follows symlinks. When given a path that is a symlink, it returns the stat of the target of the symlink.
- `lstat` doesn't follow symlinks. When given a path that is a symlink it returns the stat of the symlink and not its target.