# nodejs how to get the fs.stat birthdate value outside of the method

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to read the file created date and want to push that date to one array and send back. Its showing date when am calling it inside of fs.stat method

```
      fs.stat('./templates/'+file , function(err, stats){
      var createdDate = stats.birthtime;
      console.log(createdDate , showing date)
        })
```

but when am trying to call it oustide of that method its showing undefined

```
      fs.stat('./templates/'+file , function(err, stats){
      var createdDate = stats.birthtime;
        })
       console.log(createdDate , undefined)
```

Comment: `createDate` is a local variable with the scope of the function. You can try to put it out of the function, but it might not have the expected value due to asynchronous callback.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `var stats = fs.statSync('./templates/'+file);` instead.
According to [having-trouble-understanding-how-fs-stat-works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582105/having-trouble-understanding-how-fs-stat-works) - this operation executed synchronous without a callback.